# Why stream-line formulation is not good to solve a 2D navier-stokes problem?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, fluid-dynamics

The Navier-Stokes equation of an incompressible fluid is

$$\begin{align} \nabla \cdot \mathbf{u} & = 0 \tag{1}\label{1}\\ \dfrac{\partial \mathbf{u}}{\partial t} + \left(\mathbf{u} \cdot \nabla\right) \mathbf{u} & = -\nabla p + \mu \cdot \nabla^2 \mathbf{u}\label{2}\tag{2}\end{align}$$

I want to solve the [Lid-driven cavity problem](https://www.cfd-online.com/Wiki/Lid-driven_cavity_problem), which is a $2$D problem, in a $(1 \times 1)$ square domain.

I read the problems of a numeric fluid's algorithm come mainly from:

- There's no equation for the pressure. One way to *bypass* it is by using the [Projection method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projection_method_(fluid_dynamics)).
- When computing the next step (using finite differences for example), $\mathbf{u}$ must satisfy \eqref{1}.

To ignore these problems, I thought about

- Using the variable $s$ (stream line), which satisfies automatically \eqref{1}
- Taking the rotational of \eqref{2}, to get rid of the pressure.

$$u = \dfrac{\partial s}{\partial y} \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \  v =  -\dfrac{ \partial s}{ \partial x}$$

Then, I get the formulation \eqref{5}! Which is only one equation, only one variable! Should be simpler to solve!

$$\boxed{\nabla^2 \dfrac{\partial s}{\partial t} = \underbrace{\mu \nabla^4 s}_{\text{diffusion}} + \underbrace{\left(\dfrac{\partial s}{\partial x} \dfrac{\partial^3 s}{\partial y^3}-\dfrac{\partial s}{\partial y} \dfrac{\partial^3 s}{\partial x\partial y^2}+\dfrac{\partial s}{\partial x} \dfrac{\partial^3 s}{\partial x^2\partial y}+\dfrac{\partial s}{\partial y} \dfrac{\partial^3 s}{\partial x^3}\right)}_{\text{advection}}}\label{5}\tag{5}$$

The fourth derivative is ugly, but with appropriate elements, it should work.

I tried to implement a numeric solution using FEM on the equation \eqref{5}, but I got terrible results. The oscillates too much in the interior compared with FDM (finite differences method) using the projection method.

**Question:** Does anyone know why this approach doesn't work? Is it a formulation problem or a numeric problem?

**More details:**

> My domain is a square $ \Omega = \left[0, \ 1\right] \times \left[0, \ 1 \right]$.
>
> The boundary conditions (like [shown here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4633857/how-to-transform-the-boundary-conditions-between-formulations-of-pde-2d-fluid-f)) are
>
> $$s(x, y) = 0 \ \ \text{on} \ \partial \Omega$$
> $$\dfrac{\partial s}{\partial x} (0, y) = \dfrac{\partial s}{\partial x} (1, y) = \dfrac{\partial s}{\partial y} (x, 0) = 0$$
> $$\dfrac{\partial s}{\partial y} (x, 1) = U_{top}(x)$$
>
> I used FEM only on the space, so I transform \eqref{5} into \eqref{6}, to use a time-integrator after that.
>
> $$s(x, \ y, \ t) = \sum_{i} \varphi_i(x, \ y) \cdot S_{i}(t)$$
> $$\mathbf{C} \cdot \dot{\mathbf{S}} = \underbrace{\mathbf{D} \cdot \mathbf{S}}_{\text{diffusion}} + \underbrace{\mathbf{S} \cdot \mathbf{A} \cdot \mathbf{S}}_{\text{advection}}\label{6}\tag{6}$$
> $$\sum_{j} \mathbf{C}_{ij} \cdot \dot{\mathbf{S}}_{j} = \sum_{j} \mathbf{D}_{ij} \cdot \mathbf{S}_{j} + \sum_{k, \ j} \mathbf{S}_{k} \cdot \mathbf{A}_{kij} \cdot \mathbf{S}_j \ \ \ \ \ \ \forall i\label{7}\tag{7}$$
>
> - $\mathbf{C}$ is a $2$D matrix computed by
>   $$\mathbf{C}_{ij} \equiv \int_{\Omega} \psi_{i} \nabla^2 \varphi_{j} \ d\Omega$$
> - $\mathbf{D}$ is a $2$D matrix computed by
>   $$\mathbf{D}_{ij} \equiv \int_{\Omega} \psi_{i} \nabla^4 \varphi_{j} \ d\Omega$$
> - $\mathbf{A}$ is a $3$D matrix, which expression is similar, but bigger. Let me know if you need.
>
> I used $2$-order and $3$-order [lagrange square elements](https://defelement.com/elements/lagrange.html), so the diffusion term wouldn't be zero. But the results were similar.
>
> The maximum eigenvalue of $\mathbf{C}$ I found was near $1$, then I took the timestep $\Delta t$ of order $0.01$.
>
> My initial state $s_0$ (time $0$) is the stationary state when $\mu = \dfrac{1}{\text{Re}}$ is very big:
>
> $$\nabla^4 s_0 = 0$$
>
> Which solution is [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4635261/solve-pde-dfrac-partial4-u-partial-x4-2-dfrac-partial4-u-partial-x)